# como compartir datos entre clases heredadas de abstract en java?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

buenas a ver si me pueden ayudar. tengo una aplicacion con el crud generator que usa una clase abstract y sus clases heredadas. mi porblema es que no puedo compartir datos entre un managed bean y las clases heredadas. 
Intente crear las clsases desde el managed bean y controlarlas desde ahi pero tampoco pude me dan como nullexception.

Para explicar mejor la situacion:

[image: 1]

 intento desde mi clase obtener datos de las clases cuentas/direccion/etc...

 desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: damn11, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta**, saludos!

Comment: ahi modifique el titulo, esta bien? gracias